# How to override list.phtml for searcing in custom module?

Tags: magento2.4.1, template-override

I want to override the product div in list.phtml for both search view and category view i have replaced list.phtml by this way

> catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">vendor_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

But it only override "product-item-info" div in list.phtml in category view when access product through search the "product-item-info" div in list.phtml is not replaced.How can i override the list.phtml in custom module for search also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core layout is there:
`vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml`

Make changes in your custom `catalogsearch_result_index.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">vendor_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: thanks it worked!

Comment: @Magento2-learner Great to hear! :)